# HLMT2PDF list type is not supported

Tags: css, html2pdf

I am generating Pdfs using `HTML2PDF` but my issue is that its not supporting list-style property

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li type="a">Coffee</li>
  <li type="a">Tea</li>
  <li type="a">Milk</li>
</ul>
```

but generated list is

```
1 Coffee
2 Tea
3 Milk
```

I also tried this

```
<ul>
  <li style="list-style : lower-alpha">Coffee</li>
  <li style="list-style : lower-alpha">Tea</li>
  <li style="list-style : lower-alpha">Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<ul style="list-style-type:square">
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>Tea</li>
<li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

HTML2PDF might support this.
In unordered List every list need not have to consist a type.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple use like this

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

```
No need to use like this if you want list style 
<ul>
  <li type="a">Coffee</li>
  <li type="a">Tea</li>
  <li type="a">Milk</li>
</ul>
```